# Setter which has class instance is this possible?

Tags: java, class, getter-setter

```
    private int Li_WtVal;
        List <Integer> ValueList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        CsReader csReader = new CsReader();    

      public void setLi_WtVal(int li_WtVal) {
                ValueList = csReader.GetAllcsValues();
                li_WtVal = ValueList.get(0);
       }
    public int getLi_WtVal() {
        return Li_WtVal;
    }
}
```

And I have a while loop inside it I'm calling the setter and getter but evrytime It returns 0.

```
public int CtrlWeight(String CodeLine) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(CodeLine);
        int Li_Wtcs = 0;
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            token1 = scanner.next();
            if (token1.contains("if")){
                setLi_WtVal(Li_WtVal);
                Li_Wtcs = Li_Wtcs + getLi_WtVal() ;
            }
        }
```

Can setter has other class instances and object ref inside it?

Comment: Sure. It is just a regular method like any other. Why exactly couldn't you just try it to see?

Comment: Take care of java naming convetions. Names should be camelCase without `_`, vaiable/method name should start with lower case character,

Comment: @takendarkk but everytime it returns 0 to the getter

Comment: We need to see more code or you should learn how to debug

Comment: Ok I'll update the question :)

Comment: @Jens Done..You can see the code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the value to the parameter not to the property:

```
 public void setLi_WtVal(int li_WtVal) {
            ValueList = csReader.GetAllcsValues();
            Li_WtVal= ValueList.get(0);
   }
public int getLi_WtVal() {
    return Li_WtVal;
```

I think the reason is because your teriable naming of the variables.

Also Looks like your code doesn't make much.

Comment: Yeah. That was the issue thank you.. We can't change the variable names here  It's hard for me too:(